# Remote Use of Camera for Mac OS

Tags: macos, mac, camera

I'd like to be able to take pictures of documents I've on my desk using a digital camera mounted above my desk. What I'm looking for is some software/camera that allows me to press a button/run a script from my Mac (happy to do it on my Unix box as well if easier) and have the image file land on my desktop (so I can run OCR ectra)

Any ideas of software or cameras that might help - ideally cheap camera...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The term you're looking for is tethered shooting mode. You can get a list of cameras that work in tethered mode with gphoto here http://gphoto.sourceforge.net/doc/remote/ . If they work in gphoto, then you know that they'll also work on Mac, but you may need expensive Mac software such as Lightroom or Aperture.

It is possible that some of the camera vendors also offer the software. Googling on tethered shooting should give you quite a few good links, such as http://www.awardsounds.co.uk/how-take-tethered-photos-using-iphoto

If you want to go the linux route, it looks like gphoto will do it for you.